# parsing xml file by dom4j

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I am parsing a xml file by dom4j. Here's what the file looks like:

```
<bug>
<bug_id>1232131<bug_id>
<long_desc isprivate="0">
<who name="Alan John">alanjohn@whatever.com</who>
<thetext>asdasdasdsadasdasdasd
asdasdad
adasd
adinadasbdk
asdasdad</thetext>
</long_desc>

<long_desc isprivate="0">
<who name="Bob Dan">bdan@whatever.com</who>
<thetext>asdasdasdsadasdasdasd
asdasdadads
adasdojojjtjghjthnjthntjhnjthn
adinadasbdk
asdasdad</thetext>
</long_desc>

</bug>
```

There are several long_desc in one bug tag, also there are several bug tag in the xml file.

I used dom4j to print the content in  but I failed here's my code.

```
File f = new File("c:/Users/ah/bugs01.xml"); 
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader(); 
    Document doc = reader.read(f); 
    Element root = doc.getRootElement(); 
    Element foo; 
    for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator("bug"); i.hasNext();) { 
        foo = (Element) i.next();
        System.out.println("Text" + foo.elementText("thetext"));
        }
```

But I got null for each println. Why? I am new to dom4j and I hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Your XML isn't valid:

```
<thetext>asdasdasdsadasdasdasd
asdasdadads
adasdojojjtjghjthnjthntjhnjthn
adinadasbdk
asdasdad</text>
```

has a different start (`<thetext>`) and end (`</text>`) tag.  Also, `thetext` is a child of `long_desc`, not `bug`.

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo. I fixed the tag to be </thetext>

Comment: My xml file has no problem. There must be something wrong with my code.

Comment: You are iterating over the bug element, but you then need to iterate over the long_desc elements and *then* get the text from the text node.

Comment: So, if I want to print both bug_id and thetext? what should I do? Thanks a lot

Comment: Like println bug_id then all thetext in this bug_id, the next bug_id, all thetext...

Comment: When iterating through each bug, iterate through their list of <long_desc> as well, and print the <thetext>

Comment: for (Iterator i = root.elementIterator("long_desc"); i.hasNext();) { 
        foo = (Element) i.next();
        System.out.println("Text" + foo.elementText("thetext"));
        }

Comment: Iterate over ``bug``, then for each ``bug`` iterate over ``long_desc`` then for each ``long_desc`` grab the ``text``

Comment: I changed the code to this but it doesn't print anything for thetext. Sorry should I also change other things? Thanks